# How to print String after async function with promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, speech-to-text

I want to print "sentence" String after recognizeFile function have finished to translate from speech to text, i think i should use premises to wait the function to finish but i don't know how to do it.

```
var button = document.querySelector('#button');
var recognizeFile = require('watson-speech/speech-to-text/recognize-file');
var token;
var sentence;
button.onclick = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url : "/api/fetch-token",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(token){
            recognizeFile({
                token: token,
                file: '/Us_English_Broadband_Sample_1.wav',
                outputElement: sentence,
                play: true
            }).then(alert(sentence));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: As per your current implementation, `recognizeFile` should return a promise. Post the code of that function.

Comment: i'm not sure of what i did, probably it's just incorrect, this is the function, not implemented by me
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk/blob/master/speech-to-text/recognize-file.js

Comment: this is the doc of the function 
http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/speech-javascript-sdk/master/module-watson-speech_speech-to-text_recognize-file.html

Comment: @FabioPercivaldi are you facing then is not a functio error?? check it into console in browser..

Comment: it actually works, it just prompt out "undefined" instead of the speech-to-text translation that i'm expecting, so basically it prompts out before the function finish to read the file i think

Comment: @FabioPercivaldi I have checked the git-hub link that you have shared. probably it does not return any promise object. thus you can't apply then. It returns stream object.

Comment: okay thank you, so how can i get the translation? is it correct to use the outputElement parameter? or should i use the stream object returned?